# Nagios: snmpget works but check_snmp times out

Tags: linux, snmp, nagios

I'm trying to get Nagios to extract some SNMP information from my ADSL router but it doesn't want to work.

If I run snmpget as follows then it instantly returns the expected value

> $> snmpget -c public 192.168.11.1 iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 -v1
>
> iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (23054300) 2 days, 16:02:23.00

but if I run the equivalent check with the Nagios check_snmp tool it times out

> $> /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H localhost -C public -o iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 --protocol=1
>
> CRITICAL - Plugin timed out while executing system call

Interestingly, I run the snmpget command without specifying the protocol version then it also times out. So, I wonder whether check_snmp is actually honouring the --protocol=1 parameter.

I've also tried querying the local snmpd service on the server and that behaves in the same way so it's not a question of firewalls or routing.

Comment: This seems to be off-topic as it is not about _programming_.  It probably belongs on [sf]

Comment: 192.168.11.1 and localhost are not the same thing, surely?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, here was my fix:

Changed out the word `iso` for `1` (`iso.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0  ->  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0`). I used this command to do it:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp -H localhost -C public -o 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 --protocol=1
```

Answer (score -1):

This is old, but anyway:

the check_snmp command lacks the -m and the -p flags.

```
-m, --miblist=STRING
```

If you want to use mib files you need to specify which one to use or:

```
-m all
```

You also need to specify the protocol:

```
-P 2c
```

Comment: [`-P` _is_ `--protocol`](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_snmp.html). Furthermore, no MIBs are being used here.